# Debugging Slim Framework with XDebug

Tags: xdebug, slim

I am trying to use XDebug with Slim Framework 2. When I run a route using Postman - say

```
$app->get('/helloWorld', function() use ($app) { ................
```

it is working fine, but xdebug doesn't seem to get inside the function ever. I have trying putting in breakpoints and also debugged line by line.

In the Slim::run() function - $this->response->finalize() gets the $body.

PHP Version - 5.6.19
XDebug - 2.4.0

Comment: What is the IDE or the text editor you are using ?

Comment: @SahanSerasinghe I am using Sublime Text, but also tried Chrome XDebug extension - same happened in both the cases.

Comment: I suppose XDebug doesn't work with Slim. Only way to debug seems - http://docs.slimframework.com/errors/debug/ Let me also know whether you got Xdebug+Slim working